# Neo4j Cypher: check attributes of not consecutive nodes in path

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have got a graph that represents several bus/train stops in different cities.
Lets assume I want to go from city A (with stops a1, a2, a3...) to city Z (with stops z1, z2...)

There are several routes (relations) between the nodes and I want to get **all** paths between the start and the end node. My cost vector would be complex (travel time and waiting time and price and and and...) in reality, therefore I cannot use shortestpaths etc. I managed to write a (quite complex) query that does what I want: In general it is looking for each match with start A and end Z that is available.

I try to avoid looping by filter out results with special characteristics, e. g.

```
MATCH (from{name:'a1'}), (to{name:'z1'}),
path = (from)-[:CONNECTED_TO*0..8]->(to)    
WHERE ALL(b IN NODES(path) WHERE SINGLE(c IN NODES(path) WHERE b = c))
```

Now I want to avoid the possiblity to visit one city more than once, e. g. instead of a1-->a2-->d2-->d4-->a3-->a4-->z1 I want to get a1-->a4-->z1.

Therefore I have to check all nodes in the path. If the value of n.city is the same for consecutive nodes, everything is fine. But If I got a path with nodes of the same city that are not consecutive, e. g. cityA--> cityB-->cityA I want to throw away that path.

How can I do that? Is something possible?

I know, that is not really a beatiful approach, but I invested quite a lot of time in finding a better one without throwing away the whole data structure but I could not find one. Its just a prototype and Neo4j is not my focus. I want to test some tools and products to build some knowledge. I will go ahead with a better approach next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question. The important thing to observe here is that a path that never revisits a city (after leaving it) must have fewer transitions between cities than the number of distinct cities. For example:

- AABBC (a "good" path) has 3 distinct cities and 2 transitions
- ABBAC (a "bad" path) also has 3 distinct cities but 3 transitions

With this observation in mind, the following query should work (even if the start and end nodes are the same):

```
MATCH path = ({name:'a1'})-[:CONNECTED_TO*0..8]->({name:'z1'})
WITH path, NODES(path) as ns
WITH path, ns,
  REDUCE(s = {cnt: 0, last: ns[0].city}, x IN ns[1..] |
    CASE WHEN x.city = s.last THEN s ELSE {cnt: s.cnt+1, last: x.city} END).cnt AS nTransitions
UNWIND ns AS node
WITH path, nTransitions, COUNT(DISTINCT node.city) AS nCities
WHERE nTransitions < nCities
RETURN path;
```

The `REDUCE` function is used to calculate the number of transitions in a path.

Comment: That's a great idea! It works as expected. Now I just have to integrate my other statements. If I am running into problems I would write again. Thanks a lot!